# How to run multiple scripts , multiple times

Tags: python

I have two scripts that return values. The values of one scipt are #used by the second large script. I am trying to run both multiple times #from a separate main() script, while changing a variable in each every #time they run. I can run them once without a problem but I cannot repeat #the process,   what am I doing wrong?

Script 1.py:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
var1 =5
var2 =10
var3= 20
var4= 30
var5= 40
```

Script 2.py :

```
import Script1
question=input('What variable do you want to use ??')
def mult(question):
    [i*eval(question) for i in list1]

mult()
```

Now, I want to run this automatically n times.
I tried:

Script3.py (main program):

```
import Script2
for i in range(0,10):
    import Script2
```

but it only runs once and stops.
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's with the random hashtags in your question?

Comment: I would read up on object oriented programming. https://medium.com/the-renaissance-developer/python-101-object-oriented-programming-part-1-7d5d06833f26

Comment: leave the hashtags...ignore, I need an answer to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment

> The values I put them in by hand...then import them to the second
>   script modify them based on what i want to analyse then wait for the
>   output. ...I mean I can fuse scipt 1 and 2 together, I was hoping to
>   be pointed to some Os.module and subprocess and learn something..(i
>   can do OOP) ..new. ...Like, os.execute(Script2) n times.....I guess
>   that dont exist ?

I would reccomend the following structure then change / add  methods in Script3.py to accomplish your tasks.

Script1.py

```
from Script2 import  Script2

Script2 = Script2()

Script2.getInput()
```

Script2.py

```
from Script1 import Script1

class Script2:

    data = Script1()

    list1 = data.returnList()

    def getInput(self):

        for i in self.list1:
            question = input("What variable would you like to change? ")
            variable = input("Enter the variable: ")

            self.data.setVariable(question, variable)
```

Script3.py

```
class Script1:

    def __init__(self):
        self.list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
        self.var1 = 5
        self.var2 = 10
        self.var3 = 20
        self.var4 = 30
        self.var5 = 40

    def returnList(self):
        return self.list1

    def setVariable(self, var, value):
        # use this method to set the variables
```

Answer (score -1):

For this type of scenario, I would suggest placing the lines you want to run n times in a function, then calling the function from the module you just imported.

For example, in script 2, along with the `mult()` function, also have a function that does the action that you want to be performed:

```
import Script1

def function_name():
    question=input('What variable do you want to use ??')
    mult(question)

def mult(question):
    [i*eval(question) for i in list1]
```

Once this is defined, you can import Script2 into your third script and call the specific function like so:

```
import Script2

for i in range(0,10):
    Script2.function_name()
```

Comment: my script one has 1000 variables, and script 2 has multiple methods, I wanted to keep things separate that is why i put them in two different .py files.

Comment: If you want to do it that way, create a class for your Script1.py that hosts the variables and some get methods. Then create a class for Script2.py that hosts your methods to perform your actions. Then in Script3.py call those methods.

Comment: is there no way to run a file multiple times and enter one variable each time? by the time I rewrite it as OOP, I can do it by pressing F5 100 times and entering the value by hand, 100 times. I was thinking some Os module or sub-process ??

Comment: It would take no more time than what you are already doing. Also, where are you taking in the actual values?

Comment: The values I put them in by hand...then import them to the second script modify them based on what i want to analyse then wait for the output. ...I mean I can fuse scipt 1 and 2 together, I was hoping to be pointed to some Os.module and subprocess and learn something..(i can do OOP) ..new. ...Like, os.execute(Script2) n times.....I guess that dont exist ?

Comment: Added a solution for you.